# Being more concise React

Tags: reactjs

This is my React hw, (it works, I have been trying to wrap my head around concepts in order to either do less tables for the JSX or anything really).  Anything to make it to where I don't have to make a model of anything more than once tables or whatever be it :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const groceryList = (State1, State2, State3, State4,Pop1, Pop2, Pop3,Pop4,Cap1,Cap2, Cap3, Cap4) => {
    return (
        <table>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Capital</th>
        <tr>
          <td>{State1}</td>
          <td>{Pop1}</td>
          <td>{Cap1}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{State2}</td>
          <td>{Pop2}</td>
          <td>{Cap2}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{State3}</td>
          <td>{Pop3}</td>
          <td>{Cap3}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{State4}</td>
          <td>{Pop4}</td>
          <td>{Cap4}</td>
        </tr>
        
         
      </table>
    );
  };
  
  ReactDOM.render(
    groceryList('Idaho', 'Tennessee', 'Main', 'Wisconsin', '', '6.65 Million', '1.31 Million', '5.779 Million', 'Boise', 'Nashville', 'Agusta', 'Madison'),
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this to break it into reusable components. I would probably make a table row a component...

```
// TableRow.js
import React from "react";

function TableRow(props) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.state}</td>
      <td>{props.population}</td>
      <td>{props.capital}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default TableRow;
```

A table component that uses the JavaScript map function to map rows to the table from an array...

```
// Table.js
import React from "react";
import TableRow from "./TableRow";

const states = [
  { state: "Massachusetts", population: 6000000, capital: "Boston" }
];

function Table(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Population</th>
      <th>Capital</th>
      {states.map((state) => (
        <TableRow
          state={state.state}
          population={state.population}
          capital={state.capital}
        />
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

And then an App component that displays the table...

```
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import Table from "./Table";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will study this in great detail! I was honestly wanting stuff with conditional loops approach, but I am (I hope I don't sound ungrateful). This is great also! I just go to the section on components this morning!

Comment: No problem! You wouldn’t want to use a loop in JSX code. Instead, you want to use an expression that evaluates to something. In this case, the map function returns an array of TableRow components. React will render all the components in the array.

Comment: Thank you so much I will practice with this! I may try to post my failed attempt on this when I get to it now (I am currently in class based components haha).  Once again sir thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array of objects and pass it as a prop. This works for you because all objects will have same structure and you are rendering them as `<td>` elements. So you can map over the array and display your items.

```js
const GroceryList = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Capital</th>
      </tr>
      {items.map(({ state, pop, cap }) => (
        <tr>
          <td>{state}</td>
          <td>{pop}</td>
          <td>{cap}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

const items = [
  { state: "Idaho", pop: "6.65 Million", cap: "Boise" },
  { state: "Tennessee", pop: "1.31 Million", cap: "Nashville" },
];

ReactDOM.render(<GroceryList items={items} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
th { text-align: left }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - is a method which returns a transformed array from an array.

[`{state,pop,cap}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) - here we are destructuring the object, by using property names.

Comment: Just use `<tr>` instead of Fragments since it has to be in a `tr` element anyway.

Comment: thanks @Jacob. missed that part